# How to modify two polygons which have common point and line at the one time

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I would like to modify two polygons at the one time because these two data have same points and lines. Is it possible?

In the present circumstance, I have to modify polygon one by one. First, I modify one polygon. After that, another polygon will be modified with snap function for overlapping to another polygon.

Comment: Are you using a shapefile that has line topology instead of polygon topology?  You should just need to grab the vertex and drag that to a new position and change the shape of all the polygons.

Comment: I might missed it, but could you name the GIS softwate that you are using?!

Comment: I am using QGIS 1.8.0.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ArcGIS, use map topology for [editing shared geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_editing_shared_geometry/001t000000rp000000/) of shapefiles.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS go to Settings->Snapping Options and click on 'Enable Topological Editing' at the bottom of the dialog box.

Comment: QGIS 2.0 bugs out on me (known bug Win 7 x64) So I dropped to 1.8 - Do you know if there is there a topology validation/checking tool?

Comment: I believe this tool existed in V1.8 as well.  However, if the 64 bit version of QGIS is giving you problem, you could use the 32 bit version.  I use this on Windows 7 64 operating system on a daily basis with no problems.